# Adding two large numbers represented by string having comma

Tags: java, string

I want to add two large numbers represented by string.
`e.g. string1 = "25,000"
string 2 = "25,250"

Output = "50,250"`

I am able to solve to add two large numbers but how to play with comma can some one share some hint.

```
class Solution {
    public String addStrings(String num1, String num2) 
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i = num1.length() - 1, j = num2.length() - 1, carry = 0;
        while (i >= 0 || j >= 0 || carry != 0) 
        {
            int sum = carry;
            if (i >= 0) 
            sum += num1.charAt(i--) - '0';
            
            if (j >= 0) 
            sum += num2.charAt(j--) - '0';
            
            sb.append(sum % 10);
            carry = sum / 10;
        }
        return sb.reverse().toString();
    }
}
```

Another way i can think of is removing comma from input strings then adding them and finally formatting output using below code

```
String number = "1000500000.574";
double amount = Double.parseDouble(number);
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
System.out.println(formatter.format(amount));
```

Comment: Why not just use a `NumberFormat` or `DecimalFormat` instance to `parse()` as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is to first sanitize your input string to remove all of the commas. This can be done so with

`String sanitizedString = num1.replaceAll(",", "");`

The alternative would to be only run your addition logic if

`num1.charAt(i).equals(",") == false`

Comment: Can you share any working code if possible. I am not able to implement this exactly to skip comma string and same time adding comma in output

Comment: You should revisit your implementation for placing commas and depend on libraries since there are multiple ways to do it.For e.g [here](https://byjus.com/maths/use-of-commas/#:~:text=Rules%20for%20Using%20Commas&text=For%20a%20large%20number%2C%20the,right%20of%20the%20given%20number)

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if you are using the comma symbol as a decimal or hundred separator, but here's a possible solution as you seems to be using java.

```
    public String addStrings(String num1, String num2) throws ParseException
    {
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.#");
        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(df.parse(num1).toString());
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(df.parse(num2).toString());
        return df.format(a.add(b));
    }
```

that should work for your test case, if you're indeed using the comma as hundred separator.
else adapt the parser to match your specific number format.

Answer (score 0):

> *'... I want to add two large numbers represented by string. `e.g. string1 = "25,000" string 2 = "25,250"*
>
> *Output = "50,250"` ...*
>
> *Another way i can think of is removing comma from input strings ...'*

Use the *[String#replace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence))* method and *[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)* class.

```java
public String addStrings(String num1, String num2) {
    num1 = num1.replace(",", "");
    num2 = num2.replace(",", "");
    return new BigDecimal(num1).add(new BigDecimal(num2))
                               .toPlainString();
}
```

Here is an example using *[streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/index.html)* and a *[varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)* parameter.

```java
String addStrings(String... strings) {
    return Stream.of(strings)
                 .map(x -> new BigDecimal(x.replace(",", "")))
                 .reduce(BigDecimal::add)
                 .get()
                 .toPlainString();
}
```

```java
System.out.println(addStrings("25,000", "25,250"));
System.out.println(addStrings("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"));
```

Output

```
50250
45
```

You could even utilize the *[BinaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html)* class as an initial parameter.

```java
String eval(BinaryOperator<BigDecimal> op, String... strings) {
    return Stream.of(strings)
                 .map(x -> new BigDecimal(x.replace(",", "")))
                 .reduce(op)
                 .get().toPlainString();
}
```

```java
String[] strings = {
    eval(BigDecimal::add, "25,000", "25,250"),
    eval(BigDecimal::subtract, "25,000", "25,250"),
    eval(BigDecimal::multiply, "25,000", "25,250"),
    eval((x, y) -> x.divide(y, RoundingMode.HALF_UP), "25,000", "25,250")
};
System.out.printf("%s%n".repeat(4).formatted(strings));
```

Output

```
50250
-250
631250000
1
```